# http.ResponseWriter returns carriage return in body

Tags: http, go

I'm doing a coding exercise developing a HTTP server using Go's `net/http` library. The server is supposed to pass a series of tests in a Gitlab pipeline. I have no access to these tests and I can't see how they are implemented.

The problem is that one test for an expected *HTTP 204 No Content* response fails as follows:

```
Expected an empty response body "", got "\n"
```

The way I build the response in my code is:

```
// w is the http.ResponseWriter of the handler function.
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
w.Header().Del("Content-Type")
w.Write(nil)
```

I also tried `w.Write(make([]byte, 0))` with the same result.

I'm testing it locally with *curl* but I can't really see the characters that are being returned in the body:

```
$ curl -i --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --request POST --data "PARAMETER=1" host:9000/path
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 16:12:21 GMT

$
```

Is the `net/http` server actually returning a carriage return, and how can I prevent this?. Thank you.

Comment: Deleting a header after header is written has no effect. Remove the header before WriteHeader. You don't need the `Write` call.

Comment: I didn't really solve the problem, but thanks.

Comment: Not writing a response does not return `\n` -- there's something else you're not showing us. Please create a [mre]

Comment: In order to be able to test it locally, I need to know what exactly in the curl output tells me if there is `\n` or not. Is it the blank line between `Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 16:12:21 GMT` and the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was looking at the wrong piece of code. Because I don't have any details about the tests, I don't really know what exact case is being tested. The comments above are correct, just using `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)` doesn't produce any carriage return in the body. No need to delete `Content-Type`. My mistake was that I was using `http.Error(w, "", http.StatusNoContent)` instead.